# ¿Cómo agregar parámetros adicionales a todas las url dinámicamente?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo varias url en un sitio y necesito agregar una url enmascarada  al final de la ruta.

Por ejemplo, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo de forma dinámica a todas las rutas de mi sitio web?

```html
<a href="https://ejemplo.com/agrtegaralgo">Texto</a>
```

Comment: Esto se hace únicamente con ayuda del servidor (se llama URL Rewriting), puedes leer más en [Yaf_Router](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.yaf-router.php) si tienes disponibilidad de PHP o de cualquier otro lenguaje backend también sirve. De lo contrario tendrás que usar [query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como concepto básico puedes probar esto:

```js
content = document.getElementById('content')
enlaces = content.querySelectorAll('a');

for (i = 0; i < enlaces.length; i++) {
  enlaces[i].href = enlaces[i].href + '?parametro1=valor1'
  console.log(enlaces[i])
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<a href="http://www.google.es/php.php?param">google</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com">microsoft</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
</div>
```

Como ves, en este ejemplo lo hago a nivel de contenedor en lugar de documento, y después realizo una búsqueda global dentro del contenedor de todos los enlaces `<a>` mediante [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que son almacenados en una variable del tipo array, en este caso denominada **enlaces**.

Luego recorro ese array aplicando, en este caso, el cambio del atributo `href` reasignandolo a lo que pides, asignandole un parametro y un valor (o lo que quieras, es solo un ejemplo).

A partir de aquí, tu decides si en lugar de limitarlo al contenido de un contenedor tipo `<div>` como en el ejemplo, lo quieres aplicar globalmente en tu documento mediante:

```javascript
enlaces = document.querySelectorAll('a')
```

Y dentro del bucle `for` tambien puedes realizar las modificaciones que creas convenientes, por ejemplo, aplicando condicionales si se dan ciertos resultados en las búsquedas de cadenas dentro de la url, para que no sea tan "global" sino que solo afecte a las urls deseadas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás buscando es [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) y [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/URL). Dos clases que brindan funciones que facilitan la manipulación de las URL.

Un ejemplo:

```js
// Pasar un literal string
var url = new URL("https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/515870/c%c3%b3mo-agregar-par%c3%a1metros-adicionales-a-todas-las-url-din%c3%a1micamente")
console.log(url)

// Imprime un string vacío porque la URL no tiene parámetros
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search)
let params2 = url.searchParams
console.log(params.toString())
console.log(params2.toString())

// Otras formas de crear parámetros
let params3 = new URLSearchParams([["foo", 1],["bar", 2]]);
let params4 = new URLSearchParams({"foo" : 1 , "bar" : 2});
console.log(params3.toString())
console.log(params4.toString())

let params5 = new URLSearchParams("nombre=Juan&alias=Johnny")
params.set("edad", 15)
console.log(params5.toString())
console.log(params5.get("alias"))
```